# Dafny method return reversed character array

Tags: arrays, dafny

I want to implement a method which takes an input array of characters and output another array consisting of the input array in reverse order. But I got error "index our of range" and "post condition might not hold"
I have no idea what happen

Here is my code:

```
predicate reversed (arr : array<char>, outarr: array<char>)
requires arr != null && outarr != null
//requires 0<=k<=arr.Length-1
reads arr, outarr
{
  forall k :: 0<=k<=arr.Length-1 ==> outarr[k] == arr[(arr.Length-1-k)]
}

method yarra(arr : array<char>) returns (outarr : array<char>)
requires arr != null && arr.Length > 0
ensures outarr != null && reversed(arr,outarr)
{
  var i:= 0;
  var j:= arr.Length-1;
  outarr := new char[arr.Length];
  outarr[0] := arr[j];
  i := i+1;
  j := j-1;
  while i<arr.Length && 0<=j<arr.Length
  invariant 0<=i<=arr.Length
  decreases arr.Length-i, j
  {
    outarr[i] := arr[j];
    i:=i+1;
    j:=j-1;
  }
  //return outarr;
 }

method Main()
{
  var s := ['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b'];
  var a,b,c,d := new char[5], new char[5], new char[5], new char[5];
  a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4] := 'y', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a';
  d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4] := 'y', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a';
  b := yarra(a);
  c := yarra(b);
  assert c[..] == a[..];
  //assert c.Length > -2;
  //assert d[0] == a[0];
  //print c; print a;
}
```

1. Error    1   index out of range  6   43
2. Error    2   A postcondition might not hold on this return path. 21  2
3. This is the postcondition that might not hold.  13  26

   stdin.dfy(6,43): Error: index out of range
   stdin.dfy(21,2): Error BP5003: A postcondition might not hold on this return path.
   stdin.dfy(13,26): Related location: This is the postcondition that might not hold.
   stdin.dfy(6,2): Related location
   stdin.dfy(6,47): Related location

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://rise4fun.com/Dafny/eLoRA) is a version of your program that verifies.

There were a few issues to fix.

First, your definition of `reversed` is ill formed, because Dafny can't see the access `outarr[k]` is in bounds. I fixed this by adding a precondition `arr.Length == outarr.Length` to `reversed`.

Next, that new precondition needs to be accounted for anywhere `reversed` is called. The only such place is in the postcondition of `yarra`, which I fixed by adding an additional postcondition `arr.Length == outarr.Length`.

Then, Dafny complains that the postcondition about `reversed` may not hold in `yarra`. This requires strengthening the loop invariant. This is a typical case where we are trying to prove something about all indices of an array by establishing it about each index one by one. In such situations, the correct loop invariant is "I've established it at every index less than the current one." The thing we're establishing in this loop is that `outarr[k] == arr[arr.Length-1-k]`, so the correct invariant is:

```
forall k | 0 <= k < i :: outarr[k] == arr[arr.Length-1-k]
```

Finally, for this to go through, we need the invariant `j == arr.Length - 1 - i`. (In fact, this invariant implies that we could get rid of `j` entirely, but I have not bothered to do so.)